# Restart a jenkins stage with default steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there any way to set some default steps to be executed whenever a stage is restarted.

The first stage of the pipeline adds few secrets from the Jenkins credentials to the running container agent. We dont want to bake the image with the secrets/keys hence we are using this approach.

This is the first step, now when the pipeline fails and has to be restarted, this stage cannot be accessed to the pipeline fails irrespectively.

Below is an example for the problem statement. If stage **stage('doing something 2')** is restarted, it wont work as **stage('getting ready')** would not execute.

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker 'customimage:1.0.0' } 
    stages {
        stage('getting ready') {
            steps {
                sh "echo 'getting things ready'"
                // Do some getting ready steps which are needed for all the next stages

            }
        }
        stage('doing something 1') {
            steps {
                sh "echo 'getting things ready'"
                // Do some stuff here

            }
        }
        stage('doing something 2') {
            steps {
                sh "echo 'getting things ready'"
                // Do some stuff here

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to manage this situation, where we can read some secrets from jenkins credentials and insert them in the container, also restart from any stage if it fails.

Comment: You can define the credentials in the `environment` directive, then they will be inject as environment variables to the shell execution on the container regardless of which step started the execution, thus allowing replays.

Comment: @NoamHelmer the containers needs to have a pem file. The "Getting Ready" stage basically creates the pem file by fetching the credentials from jenkins Credential store. Are you suggesting to add an entrypoint shel script which does that.
An example would be great if you can.

Comment: what type of Jenkins credentials are you using?

Comment: the type of credentials stored are ssh. keys

Comment: So just add something like `SSH_CREDS = credentials('my-predefined-ssh-creds')` to your environment directive, and every time you run or rebuild the pipeline it will automatically place the ssh file at the location specified in `SSH_CREDS `.